# Refreshing only one <div> in page with just regular Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

If I am not grabbing any information from the server but I want to reload/refresh a div every N seconds how do I do this?

New to javascript: I've tried something like

```
 <script type = 'text/javascript'>
    function refresh(){
        setTimeout(window.location.reload(), 10000);
    }

    </script>

    <div id='target' onLoad='refresh()'>
<?    
var =grab some rapidly changing content from the web    
print var
  ?>  
    </div>
    <div>
    some stuff that doesn't get refreshed
    </div>
```

Its not clear to me that I need AJAX if im not getting the new info from the server...so for now i'd like to know how to make it work just in javascript

EDIT: I prefer not to use a library for this basic operation so ideally I wouldn't use jquery, prototype etc.
EDIT II: Not sure why people are saying the div isnt changing...the content in it is dynamic it is grabbed (say scraped) from the web...and everytime it goes to grab stuff the stuff has changed at the source...an example could be grabbing search results from twitter which change very rapidly...

Comment: If the contents are not changing then what would you reload?

Comment: There's really no such thing as "refreshing" a div, particularly if you don't have any new content to put in it.  But I suppose you could always do `document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = document.getElementById("target").innerHTML` to "refresh" a div with its current contents.

Comment: "refreshing" a div...should be clear in context..no? There is new content to be put into the div every n seconds. The code in the div grabs the content for example. Also, I don't really get your code..what are you setting document.getElementById("target").innerHTML to and on what event are you calling what function?

Comment: why do you need to "refresh" a div that didn't change? That may clarify your intention and help us understand what you want to achieve

Comment: the content is changing...the content is dynamic as denoted by the <? ?> enclosing the variables being displayed. The point is that the variable in the div is grabbed from the web not from the native server

Comment: The reason people are saying that the content of the div isn't changing is because in your question you say "If I am not grabbing any information from the server". Based on what you have said in the comments and in your edits you do want to grab something from {some} server, as you want the content of the div to change based on {some} data, as that data set changes.

Comment: I suppose a good question from this point is, where are you getting the data that the div will contain from?

Comment: I have some advice: jQuery is written with regular javascript, and is totally worth having unless you're aiming at non-smart mobile phones or something... If you're afraid of making your website too slow by including jQuery, **don't worry:** the problem doesn't lie with jQuery...

Comment: Look into compressing files that are outputted from the server with gzip compression, minifying all HTML output that comes from your PHP, minifying all scripts and combining them into one file, minifying all CSS and combining them into one file, and caching pages that aren't going to be updated for a while so they are statically generated instead of dynamically generated via PHP every single time. That's where the HUGE improvements in speed are really noticed. Using jQuery is hardly the problem at all.

Comment: One last thing: you said you are "not grabbing any information from the server" but in your code you said "grab some rapidly changing content from the web" which means you ARE grabbing stuff from a server. I assumed the latter in the answer that I posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you do need Ajax, because by definition, that is what Ajax is. ESPECIALLY if you want to grab content from *another* website.

I know you said you want to use plain javascript, but check this out, maybe you'll like this. Take a look at this awesome jQuery plugin.
https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/

It ***VERY SIMPLE TO USE*** it let's you perform Ajax sing jQuery with one VERY BIG DIFFERENCE: you can grab content from ***ANYWHERE*** (e.g. another website where your content comes from). You just use the same jQuery.load() method or .ajax() method just like you would on your own server, except you can grab content from anywhere!

Just add the plugin script to the page (after jQuery), then use the .load() method as described [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

So in your case, you can do something like this:

```
$('div#target').load('http://somewhere.com #newContent');
```

That will get #newContent from somewhere.com and place it inside #target on your site.

You could do something like this using javascript's [setInterval](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/):

```
setInterval( function() {
    $('div#target').load('http://somewhere.com #newContent');
}, 5000); //repeat function every 5000 milliseconds
```

That will repeat whatever is inside the function(){} every 5000 milliseconds (aka 5 seconds).

You can also get content from your own site:

```
$('div#target').load('http://yoursite.com/some-page #someContent');
```

That will put #someContent and whatever is inside of it from http://yoursite.com/some-page into #target on http://yoursite.com/whatever-the-current-page-is

All in all, this is a super simple way to load content. jQuery is only 31kb in size (minified), and I believe it's worth it. There's no need to reinvent the wheel when jQuery can do what you want, and efficiently at that, unless you are trying to learn javascript in and out. If you just want your site to work (the end result is what matters), then give the *super simple* method i just explained a try.

Comment: If I still haven't convinced you to use jQuery (hehe) or you just really really want to learn actual javascript, I'd suggest looking at the jQuery source code for the .load() method and .ajax() method. as well as the source code for the plugin I mentioned. You'll notice that the code jQuery implements is basically just simple straightforward javascript that has been debugged for cross-browser use already, so you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a recursive function that will change the content of your `div` that will look like it is refreshed. Like a timer method, where every set of time will change the time. I don't know how will you get the data that will load on the `div`, with this I assume you will handle this part.

Here's the function

```
var gIndex = 1;
function refreshDiv(){
    document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = "Timer " + gIndex++;
    var refresher = setTimeout("refreshDiv()", 1000);
}

<body onLoad="refreshDiv()">
    <div>
        <span>HTML Content</span>
        <div id="target"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

You will see that a time is set when setTimeout will call again the `refreshDiv()` so this will behave like reloading the content of the div. Before the `refreshDiv()` call again, change the value of you `div`.

Comment: this doesn't reload the entire page right? since its just the 'target' div thats mentioned in refreshDiv()?...thanks ill try this and let you know if it works!

Comment: Yes, this only affect the `div`

Comment: if the content of the div is some php code like <? stuff ?> is it possible to set .innerHTML = <? stuff ?> ?

Comment: No, because php is on the server-side while JavaScript is on the client side. You can use ajax to get the value generated by php, then store it on `div`. This is like a chat or take a look about rss feeds.

Comment: but the php is turned into html by apache....and then sent to the browser. so all the browser sees is html...i don't get why it doesnt work if all the browser/client sees is html

Comment: Because once it's on the client's browser, the server can't do anything else to it.  PHP runs and outputs HTML.  HTML can't be converted back to PHP once it's been output.  If you're going to be calling in PHP, you'll need to use ajax.  If you're going to use ajax, it'll be easiest with jQuery.  If you're writing JS anyway, there's no real reason not to use jQuery, even if this is the only thing you're doing with it.

Comment: You don't necessarily want a recursive function. In this case an iterative approach would be much better, you don't want to overflow the javascript call stack.

Comment: To answer you question before ace answered too soon: If you are generating the page (including scripts) with PHP... then the answer is yes. ACE misunderstood. Javascript can be considered part of the "html" that is outputted from your server when you write php. You can use php to output all sorts of different javascripts based on different scenerios, as determined by your php scripts.

Comment: I think what ace meant is that you can't interact with php directly from javascript, but that's not what you were asking. You can, however, send HTTP requests to your php scripts using javascript and receive the result back to your javascript. That's as simple as doing what I explained in the answer I posted. You can .load() content from anywhere, including content generated by php pages. You can pass POST or GET variable using javascript to the php pages to get back different content.

Comment: ALso, ace, you didn't address the fact that the OP wants to get content from another website other than his own. An example would be getting news information from some news site like cnn.com where information can change every 5 minutes.

Comment: @trusktr: thanks for the clarification, my post is the first thing pop up in my head while reading the OP post. I just did more focus on refreshing the `div` contents.

Comment: Furr shurr. Using your solution, all he'd have to do is add the Ajax that will get the content (e.g. jQuery.load()) inside the refreshDiv() function.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you do need AJAX. Well, not the "X" part, you just need the asynchronous Javascript part. The server can return XML or JSON, but in your case it's simplest to have it just return the blob of HTML you want to put into the div.

But, you do have to make a roundtrip to the server, because nothing has changed in the browser, only the contents of the page on the server have changed.

Here's a [30-second tutorial](http://rajshekhar.net/blog/archives/85-Rasmus-30-second-AJAX-Tutorial.html) that explains everything. I'll adapt it to what you want here.

First, on the server side, you already have a PHP script, let's call it "page.php", that returns this whole HTML page. You will need to make a second PHP script, let's call it "div.php", that returns just the contents of the div.

(You could also have page.php look for a parameter, like $_GET['divonly'], and that way have only one PHP script that handles both jobs. It doesn't matter ... you can do it however you want, just as long as you have a second URL to hit on the server side to retrieve the new content for the div.)

In the HTML of page.php, you've already got:

```
<div id="target"> ... </div>
```

And now you've added div.php, which returns only the " ... ", not a full HTML page.

OK, so now, the Javascript. You don't have to use a library if you don't want to -- what's nice about the libraries is that they take care of all of the cross-browser issues.

But here's what you want, adapted from the example in pure Javascript:

```
var refreshDelay = 10000;

/* Creates the XMLHTTPRequest object depending on the browser */
function createRequestObject() {
    var ro;
    if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
        ro = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }else{
        ro = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return ro;
}
var http = createRequestObject();

/* Makes the request back to /div.php ... change the URL to whatever
   script you put on the server side to return the contents of the div only */    
function sndReq() {
    http.open('get', '/div.php');
    http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
    http.send(null);
}

/* Does the work of replacing the contents of the div id="target" when
   the XMLHTTPRequest is received, and schedules next update */
function handleResponse() {
    if(http.readyState == 4){
        var response = http.responseText;
        document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = response;
        setTimeout(sndReq(), refreshDelay);
    }
}

/* Schedules the first request back to the server. Subsequent refreshes 
   are scheduled in handleResponse() */
setTimeout(sndReq(), refreshDelay);
```

Comment: You've missed one important detail joelhardi! The OP wants to retrieve data that is NOT on his own website. For example, he'd like to load, say, the content of a DIV element that is located on cnn.com; a new ticker that constantly changes for example. The content is not on his server, let alone div.php.

Comment: I took it from the php delimiters in his sample code saying "insert changing content" and php tag on the question that he was using php on the server side to create his page and do whatever scraping. Anyway, OP can weigh in if that's not the case. If it turns out he needs to do cross-domain XHR ... well, that's something else (he can always use normal XHR as in my example and php to proxy the remote content).

Comment: True that. I didn't even think of that. It's also another option. I think it's easier to write a few simply lines of jQuery with XHR than to write jQuery *and* php. jQUery->retrievedContent instead of jQUery->php->retrievedContent

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Note that `reload` fetch info from the server.

Comment: *with just regular Javascript...*

Comment: jQuery.load() won't get content from *another* website unless you add a jQuery plugin or your own extra code. That's what the OP wants... By the way, jQuery is made using regular javascript...

Comment: @trusktr I meant fetch from the OP server (the one hosting the page)

Answer (score 0):

If you're keen on doing it yourself to avoid the overhead of including a full library like jquery you can have a look at this.

http://www.dynamic-tools.net/toolbox/ajax/

The simple ajax request demo shows how to retrieve html from a url. You'll want to replace the click trigger with a setInterval to constantly poll instead of triggering on demand.

Comment: Nice. You'll notice jQuery is built with super simple snippets just like those. They just happen to be wrapped in shortcut functions.

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to use
"The metadata can be used by browsers (how to display content or reload page), search engines (keywords), or other web services"

Comment: That does not refresh the content of a div without refreshing the whole page.

Answer (score -1):

**Short answer :**

```
1 . div 'onload' doesn't exist. So you need to register a listener for the page
    load event, or put it in "<body onload='refresh()'"
2 . function refresh(){
        setTimeout("window.location.reload()", 10000); // note the ""
    }
```

**Long answer :**

Your page doesn't refresh simply because you're function is never executed. Secondly if you put it as is, the page will get refreshed as soon as the page loads, because of setTimeout(window.location.reload(), 10000);.

As a side node, using this version of the setTimout function is not recommended, and a better approach is to pass the function as the first parameter

```
setTimeout(window.location.reload,1000); // we are passing the function,
                                         // not the function result
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: why is passing the function recommended?

Comment: Because this is safer. check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout for more information about this.

Comment: please note that you should add an event listener for you function so it is called after the page load. For your case a simple `<body onload="refresh()"` should be enough.

Comment: You're missing the point sitifensys: the OP wants to reload the content of a div, without refreshing the whole page.